# Why SSKeychain doesn't work?

Tags: ios

I wanna use SSKeychain  to save CFUUID.  But  ever  time I get CFUUID from SSKeychain  is nil...    I have read doc on github  but still don't know what's wrong with it. Waiting for help~   please~~

```
NSString *retrieveuuid = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"com.game.userinfo "account:@"uuid"];
if ( retrieveuuid == nil || [retrieveuuid isEqualToString:@""])
{
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    assert(uuid != NULL);
    CFStringRef uuidStr = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    retrieveuuid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", uuidStr];
    [SSKeychain setPassword: retrieveuuid
                 forService:@"com.game.userinfo"account:@"uuid"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing space character in `"com.game.userinfo "` on the first line (when looking up the UUID), but not in the last line when setting it. These strings should be identical.